# Define custom attributes in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 different fields in the database: `city`, `state`, `country`. How do I define another attribute in Eloquent to return one string from those 3 fields?

First approach, but it doesn't work:

```
protected $address = "";

public function getAddress() : string {
  return $this->city . $this->state . " - " . $this->country;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a new attribute which is not defined in model, you need to append that attribute to your model.

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['address'];
```

And define your attribute method:

```
/**
 * Get the address.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddressAttribute()
{
    return $this->city . $this->state . " - " . $this->country;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Attribute` to the method name to make it work:

```
public function getAddressAttribute()
{
    return $this->city.$this->state.' - '.$this->country;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: That's for attributes already mapped to the database table, though. It returns nothing when I call `$this->address`