# add new attribute to laravel eloquent collection

Tags: laravel-5, model, eloquent, attributes

I would like to push in my eloquent model an extra attribute on calculation
and I would like to use it in my blade as `$user->avatarImg`
my model method look like

```
 public function avatarImg()
 {

     if($this->hasMedia('avatar')) {
         $image = $this->getMedia('avatar');
         $img = \Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::make($image[0]->getPath())->encode('data-url');
     }
     elseif ($this->blob->file) {
         $img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($this->blob->file);
     } else {
         $img = '';
     }


     $this->user->put('avatarImg', $img);

     dd($this->user);

     return $img;

 }
```

but what I try does not working I get:

```
Call to a member function put() on null
```

how would I do this properly?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load), may help you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like property `user` does not exists in your model.
If this is User model try just

```
$this->put('avatarImg', $img);
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Tried previously does not work either ``Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put()``

Comment: Try maybe $this->avatarImg = $img;

Comment: $collection = new Collection(array($this)); $collection->put('avatarImg', $img);

Comment: doing like that would not modify the models attributes, I do after dd(Auth::user()) but I do not see the new attribute

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898954/define-custom-attributes-in-eloquent

Comment: I know this workaround but in case of api calls where I need as json the attribute value would not work